# chattr error when create a new avd with cli avdmanager on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, avd-manager

When I run the command to create a new avd (`avdmanager --verbose create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86"`), I have this error, only with the verbose flag:

```
Warning: Failed 'chattr' for /home/<username>/.android/avd/pixel.avd:
Warning:  -- chattr: Opération non supportée lors de l'initialisation des drapeaux sur /home/<username>/.android/avd/pixel.avd
```

The avd is added in the folder `~/.android/avd`. But when I try to launch with `emulator @test`, I have the error:

```
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/<username>/.android/sdk]!
```

I tried to check all related issues to the path ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, but there is nothing wrong here. The real error seems to come from the creation of the avd described above.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Change your system's locale to `en_US.UTF-8` by command `update-locale` and reboot/relogin and then rerun your command.

You may check [the man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/update-locale.8.html) for more description.

### Root cause

It's a bug of `avdmanager`, it only works well on system whose locale is English.

Here is [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-main/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/internal/avd/AvdManager.java#2367), we can see that it only excludes error msg in English.

Comment: This is disturbing.